# 1004 - Method range of object worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I coded one macro for Excel, but I have one error and don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
Dim poleInput As Variant

Public Function HasContent(text_box As Object) As Boolean
    HasContent = (Len(Trim(text_box.Value)) > 0)
End Function

Sub TextBox1_Change()
        poleInput = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If HasContent(TextBox1) Then
        MsgBox "Po¾e je prázne, pridaj nejake údaje!"
    Else
        'MsgBox (poleInput)
        AddAppointments (poleInput)
        AddAppointmentsAfterThreeMonths (poleInput)
        MsgBox "Pripomienka úspešne poslatá!"
    End If
End Sub

Sub AddAppointments(pole As String)
'Update by Extendoffice 20180608
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutItem As Object
    
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xRg = Range(pole)
    
    For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
        Set xOutItem = xOutApp.createitem(1)
        Debug.Print xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value
        xOutItem.Subject = "Posla mail " & xRg.Cells(I, 2).Value
        xOutItem.Location = "Office"
        xOutItem.Start = xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value & " 11:00"
        xOutItem.End = xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value & " 17:00"
        xOutItem.BusyStatus = 2
        xOutItem.ReminderSet = True
        xOutItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "15"
        xOutItem.Body = "Posla mail zamestnancovy " & xRg.Cells(I, 2).Value
        xOutItem.Save
        Set xOutItem = Nothing
    Next
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub AddAppointmentsAfterThreeMonths(pole As String)
'Update by Extendoffice 20180608
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutItem As Object
    
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xRg = Range(pole)
    
    For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
        Set xOutItem = xOutApp.createitem(1)
        Debug.Print xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value
        xOutItem.Subject = "Posla pripomienku " & xRg.Cells(I, 2).Value
        xOutItem.Location = "Office"
        xOutItem.Start = DateAdd("m", 3, xRg.Cells(I, 1)) & " 11:00"
        xOutItem.End = DateAdd("m", 3, xRg.Cells(I, 1)) & " 17:00"
        xOutItem.BusyStatus = 2
        xOutItem.ReminderSet = True
        xOutItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "15"
        xOutItem.Body = "Posla pripomienku zamestnancovy " & xRg.Cells(I, 2).Value
        xOutItem.Save
        Set xOutItem = Nothing
    Next
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Error is showing on this line:

```
Set xRg = Range(pole)
```

I don't understand why is problem showing, it's easy it should only parse String into range and get code up and running, but somehow these things aren't going well.

Comment: What value does `pole` hold when the error occurs?

Comment: Ahh I see, it is happening because pole is empty string. I need to fix that with some if statement. And it is empty because I havent add any info into TextBox. Is there any function which detects if textbox is filled or if its empty?

Comment: It looks like your `CommandButton1_Click()` displays a message if `textbox1` has any content, or calls `AddAppointmentsAfterThreeMonths` if it hasn't?  Might be worth renaming your buttons and text boxes to something more meaningful to.

Comment: _Is there any function which detects if textbox is filled or if its empty?_  Isn't that what `HasContent` does?  Might be worth adding another function to check that the text can be used as a range address.

Answer (score 0):

The below line

```
If HasContent(TextBox1) Then
```

is the same as

```
If HasContent(TextBox1) = True Then
```

Which is not what you want. You want to avoid an empty textbox. Change the line

```
If HasContent(TextBox1) Then
```

to

```
If HasContent(TextBox1) = False Then
```

or to

```
If Not HasContent(TextBox1) Then
```

Example

```
If Not HasContent(TextBox1) Then '<~~ Blank
    MsgBox "Blank"
Else '<~~ Not Blank
   MsgBox "Not Blank"
End If
```

This way `poleInput` will not be empty and you will not get the error that you are getting because of blank input.

Comment: `If Not HasContent(TextBox1)  Then` could also be used instead `=False`.

Comment: incorporated your suggestion above